# Difference between Great Britain, European Union, United Kingdom, Schengen Area and effects after Brexit

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, europe, event-based-effects

I have already read about the different countries on the European continent and different terminologies involved.

What would be the effects in these countries on visas after Brexit?

Can we have only one common visa to visit all these countries?

I will require the countries union names for each Union, visas issued before Brexit and after Brexit to travel to each country.

Comment: As of right now, there is no impact on visitor visas. The UK and Schengen already maintain separate visa systems, and since brexit involves a separation of the UK from the EU, the prospect of a common visitor visa that works for both the UK and Schengen seems frightfully unlikely at any point in the foreseeable future.

Comment: "I will require"?!? You are not in a position to "require" anything at all, people may choose to donate their time to helping you out by answering your question as they wish.

Comment: With regard to what you "require," nothing has changed as a result of brexit. As of today, the UK is still a member of the EU, it is still not a part of the Schengen area, and there have been no change in the visas required to travel to any of the countries concerned. If you have a specific question about the documents required to travel to a particular country, then you can ask that.

Comment: Further to @ZachLipton post, it's currently impossible to say what the effects will be after Brexit, because no one has started negotiating yet. You are asking something that is baffling leading politicians and economists around the world right now...

Comment: Even if we ignore the presumptuous wording of your exit, it is virtually nonsensical.  I cannot begin to imagine what you could possibly mean by "the countries union names for each Union."

Answer (score 6):

The UK always had its own visa regime, even within the European Union so the simple answer to your question is no, it's not possible to have a single visa to visit all these countries.

Furthermore, Ireland, Cyprus, Romania, Bulgaria, and Croatia are also in the European Union but outside the Schengen area. Some (but not all) Schengen visas allow you to visit Cyprus, Romania, Bulgaria, and Crotia. Some (but not all) Cypriot, Romanian, Bulgarian, or Croat visas allow you to visit the other countries in that list. Some (but not all) British visas allow you to visit Ireland. Best case scenario, you could be able to visit the whole EU with a multiple-entry Schengen visa and the right type of British visa. Worse case scenario (in particular single entry visas), you could theoretically require 6 or 7 visas.

Brexit is likely to have an effect on EU citizens and their relatives and in particular on the visa exemptions and simplified procedures enjoyed by the members of an EU citizen's family. I would not expect any immediate effect on other visitors from outside the EU ("third-country nationals") but it's difficult to know. That's complete speculation at this point but it could paradoxically free Ireland to join the Schengen area if it wants to (as a so-called "hard Brexit" would make it very difficult to maintain the current open border regime between the countries).

Small terminological note as you are asking about that too: Great Britain is technically the main island of the United Kingdom but "Britain" or "British" are often used to designate the whole polity (as I have done above).

Comment: This almost answers my question , but waiting for more answers and please go through edit , if you can add some more briefing on this by taking some country in relation like if you are travelling via India , that would be great .

Comment: @Yatin As I already stated, what the rules will exactly be after Brexit is not known. A list of EU countries can be found in many places, among them Wikipedia. Travelling via India does not make any difference.